# Disparity of image (closest object)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, disparity-mapping

I want to extract closest object to the camera from image in Python OpenCV. I have two images of the same object but second one is just a little bit rotated. Now what I want is to create a binary mask based on my disparity map to extract my object (ball without the yellow rectangle behind it).

[image: 1]

So after reading my two input images (A) and (B)  in the photo) I use:

```
    stereo = cv.StereoSGBM_create(numDisparities=16,blockSize=5)
    disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)
```

and for some reason I get result like (C). I mean it clearly recognizes the ball in the front but for some reason I get that white part across whole image, which dont make sense to me. So problem is that because of disparity map like this when i use the code for closing contours to get binary mask containing white only where the ball is:

```
   se = np.ones((2,2), dtype='uint8')
   image_close = cv.morphologyEx(disparity, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, se)
   plt.imshow(image_close,'gray')
   plt.show()
   cv.waitKey(0)

   thresh_image = image_close.astype(np.uint8)

   cnt = cv.findContours(thresh_image, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
   mask = np.zeros(disparity.shape[:2], np.uint8)
   cv.drawContours(mask, cnt, -1, 255, -1)
```

I get result like in (D). So the final result of extracting closest object (ball) is in (E), which is not even close to what I need. Can any1 explain to me what I am doing wrong here? Or is there any better method to extract closest object? Yellow rectangle behind the ball is there for a reason. To test if program will recognize only the ball as closest object.

Comment: the usual: swap eyes, vary parameters, consider the range of values. you're getting a 1/16 pixel (subpixel) precision disparity map.